# How to tell if observers of a rxjs Subject have finished processing the event?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm kind of new to Rxjs,  trying to determine if thre is a way to know when all of the observers of an Rxjs Subject have completed whatever they are doing in response to   .next.

For example, say I have Auth class that looks like this:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";


interface AuthEvent {
    eventName : string;
}

class Auth { 
    
    static getInstance() : Auth {
       //return a singleton of Auth
    }

    private constructor() {}

    authSubject$ : Subject<AuthEvent> = new Subject();

    login() {
        //do login things
        this.notify("login");
    }
    logout() {
        //do logout things
        this.notify("logout")
    }


    notify(event : string) {
        let evt = <AuthEvent>{};
        evt.eventName = event;
        this.authSubject$.next(evt);
    }

}
```

And lets say I have 5 different subscribers classes, all of which contain code which looks something like this

```
 class SomeWidget {

    constructor() {
       Auth.getInstance().authSubject$.subscribe( (evt) => {
           switch(evt.eventName){
             case "login": 
                this.handleLogin()
                break;
             case "logout":
                 this.handleLogout();
                 break;
            }
      });
    }
```

From my observation, it seems like when the Auth object calls `this.authSubject$.next(evt)` the subscriptions which are active on the subject seem to process asynchronously. (I'm not sure that's completely true, but it seems kind of random the order in which things complete).   That is, the notify method will return immediately, without waiting for all the subscribers to process the event.

Is there some way to for the Auth class to determine when all the widgets have finished processing the event that is triggered by `next` without putting code on the widgets themselves?  I.e. by examining something on the subject perhaps?  Or am I mistaken, and next will only return when all the subscribers have completed responding to the event?

Comment: Next doesn't return anything; RxJS uses the observer pattern, the subject is only responsible for updating all subscribers, not for what (if anything) they do as a result.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: OK thanks.  What is an XY problem Ingo?

Comment: You're asking a question for what you think you want to answer, but likely your actual problem is something else (assuming you're not asking this purely out of curiosity, but to achieve something). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: If you could share more info about why you want to know if your observers completed their work, there might be a better solution for your problem. And yes, `next` just puts new event into the stream and returns, it doesn't wait for observers to complete processing the event.

Comment: Well, my actual problem is to know when all the logic associated with login is completed.  My Auth service sends messages to a number of different components (which needs to fetch data and various other things when a user logs in or out), and all those things need to be completed setup before the app is ready to display itself.   I was hoping that if 'next' was a single threaded process which called and ran each of subscribers methods, I could just wait until next was 'done'.   Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

The observer pattern does not provide you with a (default) way to wait for all subscriber to finish processing. It decouples the emitting of events from the processing of these events.

You are correct in your observation that the subscribers of the Auth event are invoked asynchronously. You should not make assumptions on the ordering of these subscribers getting notified.

If you want to be 'notified' when your subscribers are done processing there are some ways to do so (from the top of my mind:

- inject your subscription in the auth class instead of providing the observable
  `Auth.addAuthEventObserver(Observer<AuthEvent>)`. You will also need to cater for the lifecycle of the Observer when the Widget is destroyed by having a way to notify your `Auth` class that a given Observer is no longer needed
- add a function in your Auth class to which all subscribers can emit a signal that they have 'processed' the event. Your Auth class can then add a delay on the emission of events untill all subscribers have ACK'ed their processing.

It feels like you might have to re-evaluate the responsibilities of your Observer and Observables so these kinds of hacky-feeling solutions are not needed?